# What is the meaning of 〜たりして?

Tags: usage, meaning

I've just come across "〜していたりして" at the end of a sentence in a post on Facebook, so it's probably very casual. Does anyone know the correct meaning and typical usage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

たりして is used to posit some event as a possibility but something you are not sure about. For example, about the future:

> 10年後に大金持ちになっていたりして。

From the nature of this expression meaning "not being sure", it is also used as a hedge when you want to be modest and a bit comical:

> ひょっとして、さっきのことでまだ怒ってたりして。

Comment: would ひょっとして、さっきのことでまだ怒ってたりして。 translate as "Perhaps (I) might be still mad about what happened a little while ago."?

Comment: @yadokari Something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what part you're stuck on, and we can give more relevant answers most of the time if we know the context, but here we go:

`している` is the present-continuous short form of the verb `する` (to do).

The `〜たり` suffix indicates an incomplete list of one or more actions (more on that [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5681/1272)), for example

> 新聞を読んだり、コーヒーを飲んだりする
>   Read a newspaper, drink coffee, and so on. (or)
>   Do such things as read a newspaper and drink coffee.

So the best translation I can give without the context here is:

> 〜していたりして
>   Doing such things as ~

As for why the final `する` is in て-form, that would be easier to answer if we could see the full sentence.

Comment: Your syntactic analysis is right, but you are missing the most crucial aspect: the particular nuance of this expression.