The use of たり here is unclear to me, please explain to me！
A quote taken from 女王の教室ドラマ.
It is said that 「いつまで経っても、何にも気づいたりしません。」
What is the use of たり here? I don’t understand… I couldn't wrap my mind about this. Thanks in advance

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55396/9831
